# Why "set-face-attribute" needs to be executed twice when switching from a TTF font to a bitmap font?

Tags: frames, fonts

I'm trying to write a function which switches between fonts in all
frames. In order to do this, I first wrote the following commands:

This font is a TTF font and is located in `~/.local/share/fonts/iosevka-ss04-light.ttf`.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Iosevka SS04" :weight 'light :height 250)
```

This font is a bitmap font and is located in `/usr/share/fonts/misc/5x7.pcf.gz`.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Misc Fixed" :weight 'normal :height 60)
```

The problem is that when switching between `Iosevka SS04` to `Misc Fixed`, I've to execute the second command twice. For a full
demostration, see gif below.

My question is: Is there any workaround to avoid executing the command twice?

[image]